# How to disable error squiggles in C++ code in VS Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code to program in C++ but it keeps giving me error squiggles. I tried disabling them in the settings by changing `C_Cpp error squiggles` to `disabled` but they still appear. Is there anything else I need to do to disable them as I find them very annoying?

Comment: Related for Visual Studio with Resharper: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65233303/disable-squiggly-lines-for-c-visual-studio-2019

Comment: related generalized question (not specific to c++): [How can I easily toggle display of problem underlining in VS Code editor panels?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74753185/11107541)

Answer (score 9):

#### The straightforward thing works

What you said you did works for me in VSCode 1.37.1.

Before, with defaults:

[image: Screenshot of error with squiggle]

Changing the setting:

[image: Screenshot of changing the setting]

After:

[image: Screenshot of error with no squiggle]

Excerpt of `settings.json`:

```
{
    ....
    "C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "Disabled"
}
```

#### Hypotheses about why it did not work for you

There is another `settings.json` attribute called `C_Cpp.default.enableConfigurationSquiggles`.  Might you have accidentally changed that one?

Is "C_Cpp: Intelli Sense Engine" set to "Default"?  It should be (rather than "Tag Parser") in order to disable squiggles.

Maybe the syntax error you have is different somehow?

For ease of reproduction, it would help to see your `settings.json`, `c_cpp_properties.json`, and an example of erroneous syntax with squiggles.

Comment: I have set `    "C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "disabled",
    "C_Cpp.default.enableConfigurationSquiggles":false` , not working

Comment: @alen I suggest asking a new question.  Emphasize that you have `errorSquiggles` set to disabled but still see them.  Include your `settings.json` and list of installed extensions in the question.

Answer (score 6):

Currently, there is no settings to turn the error decorations off but some language extensions implement their own solutions.

If you are looking for a language agnostic solution, you can make the squiggly lines transparent by adding following setting to general settings or workspace settings file.

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  //                                ↓↓
  "editorError.foreground": "#00000000"
}
```

For a specific language:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "[jsonc]": {
    //                                ↓↓
    "editorError.foreground": "#00000000"
  }
}
```

Please note that we use 8-digit hex value, the first six is not important but last two should be zero to make the color transparent.

Here is how you can do it programmatically in an extension:

```js
workspace.getConfiguration('workbench').update( 'colorCustomizations', {
    "editorError.foreground": "#00000000",
});
```

Answer (score 1):

just go to command palette (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>) and then search C/C++ enable error squiggles and select that. Done