# Disable squiggly lines for C++ (Visual Studio 2019)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I want to disable squiggly lines in C++ completely for taking screenshots.

I already have done so in Tools/Options

- C++ / Advanced / Disable Code Analysis Squiggles

  [image: Disable Code Analysis Squiggles]
- C++ / Advanced / Disable Intellisense Squiggles

  [image: Disable Intellisense Squiggles]

Yet, I still have squiggly lines as in this code:

```cpp
volatile const unsigned const long unsigned int volatile long u_sixtyfour5 = 42;
```

[image: Code with squiggly lines]

Where else could I find options to disable sqiggly lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I had [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) installed. Disabling Code Analysis in Resharper options helped.

[image: Resharper Code inspection settings]

I now have beautiful non-squiggled C++ code like

[image: Code without squiggles]

Comment: Jury still out on whether that line of code constitutes "beautiful" . But at least your squiggles are gone.